# ivy cannot resolve org.springframework dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ivy

I want to use the Ivy Eclipse plugin to reolve the spring-oxm dependency.

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-oxm" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE" />
```

But I got below error:

> Some projects fail to be resolved Impossible to resolve dependencies
>   of *my class name* unresolved dependency:
>   org.restlet.jee#org.restlet;2.1.1: not found unresolved dependency:
>   org.restlet.jee#org.restlet.ext.servlet;2.1.1: not found

I googled, and people say the restlet-2.1.1 no longer exist. And I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its available in this repo http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.1.1/

Probably you need to add this repository in your Ivy settings or any repository you are using.

Comment: Can you give an example of adding this to Ivy's repositories? I can't find any useful information for someone who has never used Ivy before and have no idea where the settings file is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i just now had same problem with my Solr 5.5.0 with changing repository for IVY. But that's all waste of time. 
Just download org.restlet.ext.servlet jar file from http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.servlet/2.1.1/, create folder repository near ivy-settings.xml, copy downloaded file and change ivy-settings.xml like :

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain-example"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain-example">
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" />
      <filesystem name="libraries">
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repository/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
      </filesystem>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Enjoy.